# How to inner separate a column

Tags: tables

How to use latex to make a table like the following:[image: This is made by Word. I found it is difficult to just separate the 2nd and 3rd columns.]

It should not be difficult. But just feel it is not very straight forward to get what I want.

Comment: Welcome! What have you got so far? What have you tried? Please don't expect people to do everything for you from scratch: you haven't even provided the table's content. Of course, somebody may take pity on you or be so taken by the appeal of your target that they do your work for you. But you stand a better chance of getting useful help if you show us what code you have and ask a specific question about whatever is giving you trouble.

Comment: To sum up: please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a beginning, I let you the rest as exercice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,calc,ragged2e,multirow}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\Centering}m{.22\linewidth}|*{4}{>{\Centering}X|}}\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{}
&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Sim1:}
&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Sim2:}\\
&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{
    $\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
     y1=(x6-E(x6))2-x4\\
     \hspace{\stretch{2}}\times x5\hspace{\stretch{1}}\strut
    \end{array}$}
&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{
    $\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
     y1=(x6-E(x6))2-x4\\
     \hspace{\stretch{2}}\times x5\hspace{\stretch{1}}\strut
    \end{array}$}\\\hline
Method & SQB & \makebox[0pt]{conventional} & SQB & \makebox[0pt]{conventional} \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Or with a more modern look :

[image]

\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx,calc,ragged2e,multirow}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\Centering}m{.22\linewidth}*{4}{>{\Centering}X}}\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{Sim1:}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{Sim2:}\\
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
    $\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
     y1=(x6-E(x6))2-x4\\
     \hspace{\stretch{2}}\times x5\hspace{\stretch{1}}\strut
    \end{array}$}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
    $\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
     y1=(x6-E(x6))2-x4\\
     \hspace{\stretch{2}}\times x5\hspace{\stretch{1}}\strut
    \end{array}$}\\\cmidrule(lr{\tabcolsep}){2-3}\cmidrule(lr{\tabcolsep}){4-5}
Method & SQB & \makebox[0pt]{conventional} & SQB & \makebox[0pt]{conventional} \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```